# Export Multiple Sheets to TSV Using Macro Button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, export-to-csv

EDIT
*I copy and pasted from [Google Sheets: Exporting to TSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624655/google-sheets-exporting-to-tsv) however how do i get it to get the data only from a select few sheets and not every sheet? thank you
*

I've tried looking online for answers, but I'm not that great at Script Editing yet,

I'm trying to make a Macro that when I click a button (already Made) it will export 7 sheets to TSV on my G Drive, preferably in a folder named with today's date (With the file named as the stores '1' '2' etc (name of the sheets).

When I tried the record Macro all I got was the following,

```
function DownloadOrders() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('1'), true);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('2'), true);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to use the script you found but modify the "saveAstsv()" function and add the "make one tsv function);

```
function saveAstsv() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // create a folder from the name of the spreadsheet
  var folder = DriveApp.createFolder(ss.getName().toLowerCase().replace(/   /g,'_') + '_tsv_' + new Date().getTime());

  makeOneTsv("Sheet A",folder);
  makeOneTsv("Sheet B",folder);


  Browser.msgBox('Files are waiting in a folder named ' + folder.getName());
}



function makeOneTsv(sheetName,folder){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
fileName = sheet.getName() + ".tsv";
var tsvFile = convertRangeTotsvFile_(fileName, sheet);
folder.createFile(sheetName, tsvFile);



}
```

I haven't tested this but it should do what you want if you remove any typos.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for replying! :)
When i try that is gives an error saying it cant find openByName? 

I'm going to buy a 'For Dummies' Guide!

Comment: getSheetByName (sorry, I was thinking of files)

Comment: Thanks! i'll have a go at this - been bogged down with other stuff!